# Using ViewHolder With ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewholder

I am using ListView to List text and images but I want to use ViewHolder to make the scrolling more smooth I have tried but can't quite get it right how must I modify the code

The way I have tried some of my images doesn't show up

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return text1.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return text1[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater infla=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View v = infla.inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout, null);

    TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    TextView tv3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    ImageView iv3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    TextView tv4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    ImageView iv4 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    TextView tv5 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    ImageView iv5 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    TextView tv6 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    ImageView iv6 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    TextView tv7 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    ImageView iv7 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView7);

    tv1.setText(text1[position]);
    iv1.setImageResource(text2[position]);
    tv2.setText(text3[position]);
    iv2.setImageResource(text4[position]);
    tv3.setText(text5[position]);
    iv3.setImageResource(text6[position]);
    tv4.setText(text7[position]);
    iv4.setImageResource(text8[position]);
    tv5.setText(text9[position]);
    iv5.setImageResource(text10[position]);
    tv6.setText(text11[position]);
    iv6.setImageResource(text12[position]);
    tv7.setText(text13[position]);
    iv7.setImageResource(text14[position]);

    if(text2[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
        iv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }if(text3[position].matches("")) {
        tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }if(text4[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
        iv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }if(text5[position].matches("")) {
        tv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }if(text6[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
        iv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }if(text7[position].matches("")){
        tv4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }if(text8[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
        iv4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }if(text9[position].matches("")){
        tv5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }if(text10[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
        iv5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }if(text11[position].matches("")){
        tv6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }if(text12[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
        iv6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }if(text13[position].matches("")){
        tv7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }if(text14[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
        iv7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: You need to use `ViewHolder` pattern for better performance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricks:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder;
if( convertView == null ){
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.tv=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    holder.iv=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ...
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}else {
    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}

holder.tv.setText(text1[position]);
holder.iv.setImageResource(text2[position]);
...
//handle with your widgets cached in ViewHolder
return convertView;
```

}

And `ViewHolder` is here:

```
public class ViewHolder{
    TextView tv;
    ImageView iv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a static ViewHolder Class that holds your view in your adapter.

more like this one:

```
static class ViewHolder {
public TextView text;
public ImageView image;
}
```

And that viewholder will be used as a holder of view where you initialized its view in the `getView` method and set it as a tag so you can recycle it later for other item in the list.

You can follow [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) to apply the viewholder pattern of listview

Answer (score 0):

Your need to make use of the `convertView` sent across in `getView()` method for optimizing working.
Read my [blog](https://bansal21ankit.wordpress.com/2014/04/09/optimized-listview-having-listener-within-the-row-items/) from properly optimizing the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

The Viewholder pattern is used to cache the Views of the list item in a holder class so you don't have to call inflate view or `findViewById()` for every list item in the `ListView`. By making a class where you can hold keep a reference to all the ChildViews in the list item. Usually this is a inner static class.

The `View convertView,` parameter in the `getView()` method is the view that is cached by the Android system already. So you start with an if statement where you inflate a list item if convertView is null. You also set all the childview references on the viewholder there. Then you add the instance of the viewholder class as a tag to the `convertView` with `setTag()`. In the else part of the if statement you just get the viewholder from the `convertView` with `getTag()`. No you have the viewHolder and can actually update the listview item with new data.

I hope this explains what you need to if not here are some links to some better rescources then my explaination.

- [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_example)
- [Hold View Objects in a View Holder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)
- [Android ViewHolder Pattern Example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

-here is the mmodified adapter to make the scroll more smooth using the viewholder pattern to reuse the item instead of create new one each time you scroll.

```
/**
 * Created by Ziad on 4/22/2015.
 */
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return text1.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return text1[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        ViewdHolder holder=null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater infla=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();


            View v = infla.inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout, null);

            holder = new viewdHolder();

            holder.tv1= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.iv1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.tv2 =(TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.iv2= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            holder.tv3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            holder.iv3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            holder.tv4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            holder.iv4  = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            holder.tv5= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            holder.iv5  = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            holder.tv6 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            holder.iv6 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
            holder.tv7 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            holder.iv7 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView7);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewdHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }




        holder.tv1.setText(text1[position]);
        holder.iv1.setImageResource(text2[position]);
        holder.tv2.setText(text3[position]);
        holder.iv2.setImageResource(text4[position]);
        holder.tv3.setText(text5[position]);
        holder.iv3.setImageResource(text6[position]);
        holder.tv4.setText(text7[position]);
        holder.iv4.setImageResource(text8[position]);
        holder.tv5.setText(text9[position]);
        holder.iv5.setImageResource(text10[position]);
        holder.tv6.setText(text11[position]);
        holder.iv6.setImageResource(text12[position]);
        holder.tv7.setText(text13[position]);
        holder.iv7.setImageResource(text14[position]);



        if(text2[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
            holder.iv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(text3[position].matches("")) {
            holder.tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(text4[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
            holder.iv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(text5[position].matches("")) {
            holder.tv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(text6[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
            holder.iv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(text7[position].matches("")){
            holder.tv4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(text8[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
            holder.iv4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(text9[position].matches("")){
            holder.tv5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(text10[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
            holder.iv5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(text11[position].matches("")){
            holder.tv6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(text12[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
            holder.iv6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(text13[position].matches("")){
            holder.tv7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(text14[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
            holder.iv7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }




        return v;
    }


    class ViewdHolder {




        TextView tv1;
        ImageView iv1 ;
        TextView tv2 ;
        ImageView iv2;
        TextView tv3 ;
        ImageView iv3 ;
        TextView tv4 ;
        ImageView iv4 ;
        TextView tv5 ;
        ImageView iv5 ;
        TextView tv6 ;
        ImageView iv6 ;
        TextView tv7 ;
        ImageView iv7 ;


    }



}
```